For which numbers of animals, can positions of wheel match exactly one head and body at a time
A turnable wheel is attached flat to a wall.  Evenly spaced around the edge of the wheel, are painted the heads of n different animals.  Evenly spaced around the wheel on the wall, are painted the bodies of the n animals.

For which numbers n can we arrange the heads and bodies so that exactly one head and body match at a time (when the pictures on the wheel and wall are aligned)?
Answers must be fully justified to be accepted.
Source: I thought of this question when I saw the object at the zoo.  However it is a natural enough question to ask, and it would not surprise me if it has  been posed elsewhere.  I sometimes use it to help people practice maths interviews.

There is a contradiction between text and image - the shown wheel matches at most (not exactly) one head and body at a time. E.g. after turning the wheel by 180 degrees, none of the positions match.

@Imre Yes I was not completely happy with how I worded it, though I think people understood.  I have added a bit in parentheses to resolve this.


 It is possible if and only if n is odd.
 Putting the inner halves in the reverse order shows it is possible when n is odd.


 Suppose it is possible with n animals.
 Number the outer parts $0, 1, ... n-1$, and let $a_0, a_1, ... a_{n-1}$ be the locations of the inner parts matching $0, 1, ...   (n-1)$.
 Piece i will match then the inner wheel is turned back $a_i - i  \left(\text{mod } n\right)$ positions.

 Since exactly one animal is correct in each position, the numbers $a_0 - 0, a_1 - 1, ... a_{n-1} - (n-1)$ must be a permutation of $0, 1, ... (n-1) \left(\text{mod } n\right)$.
 So  $(a_0 - 0) + (a_1 - 1) + ... + (a_{n-1} - (n-1)) \equiv 0 + 1 + ... + (n-1)  \left(\text{mod } n\right)$
 So  $\left(a_0 + a_1 + ... a_{n-1}\right) - (0 + 1 + ... + (n-1)) \equiv 0 + 1 + ... + (n-1) \left(\text{mod } n\right)$.

 But $a_0, a_1, ... a_{n-1}$ is a permutation of $0, 1, ... (n-1)$.
 So $\left(0 + 1 + ... + (n-1)\right) - \left(0 + 1 + ... (n-1)\right) \equiv 0 + 1 + ... + (n-1) \left(\text{mod } n\right)$.
 so $0 \equiv 0 + 1 + ... + (n-1)\ \equiv n \frac{n-1}{2} \left(\text{mod } n\right) $


 If n is odd, then the last expression is $n \frac{n-1}{2}$, and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ is an integer so $n \frac{n-1}{2} \equiv 0\left(\text{mod } n\right)$.

 If n is even i.e. $n = 2k$, the last expression is $\left(2k-1\right) \cdot 2k / 2 = (2kk - k) = (nk - k) = k \left(\text{mod } n\right)$.  Since $0 < k < n$, this is not congruent to $0 \text{ mod } n$, so a solution with an even number of animals is impossible.


Perfect solution.

I know that

 When n is odd, labelling the points on the wheel as 1, 2, …, n clockwise and labelling the points on the wall as 1, 2, …, n anticlockwise, with the two 1s coinciding initially, satisfies the given requirement.

However,

 This doesn’t work when n is even. I believe it’s impossible when n is even but I don’t have a proof of this yet.


A good start (+1).
